# JPA validation ignores columnDefinition

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I got following definition on a createTable in liquibase:

```
<column name="FOO" type="CHAR(3)">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

When I run this agains a local postgres:latest docker database the datatype is correctly setup as CHAR(3).

When I now define my entity with the following:

```
@Column(name = "FOO", nullable = false, length = 3, columnDefinition = "char")
private String foo;
```

and enable jpa-validation in spring-boot I get the following error:

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [foo] in
> table [my_schema.my_table]; found [bpchar (Types#CHAR)], but expecting
> [char(3) (Types#VARCHAR)]

Why? And how can I fix this? The field is allowed to be exactly 3 characters all the time.

EDIT:
There is no bpchar and I think hibernate does not pick this up correctly: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate ignores `columnDefinition` in validation, only for initialization. To set a column type use `@JdbcTypeCode` annotation:

```
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
@Column(name = "FOO", nullable = false, length = 3)
private String foo;
```